# How to ask about how to eat certain kinds of fruits?

Tags: questions, food

There are a lot of fruits in tropical regions that we should know the right way to eat them. I want to ask locals about how should I eat for example [Durian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durian). Which question is the best?

1. "How Durian should be eaten?"
2. "How should I eat Durian?"
3. "What is the right way to eat Durian?"

Comment: With nose plugs....

Comment: @Jim "They taste like heaven, but smell like hell".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Australian English, to ask the proper way to do something, you would ask:
How do you [do something]?

So I would ask: 
How do you eat durian?

Your second two examples would also be correct, but less common.

Your first example has the wrong word order, it should be:
How should durian be eaten?

Comment: Quite right, but what's uniquely Australian about that?

Answer (score 2):

I would ask the question "What is the correct way to eat durian?" Or "How should durian be eaten?"

Answer (score -2):

I think I may say like "What is the right way to eat durian?" Or "How do you eat durian?" Or "How should I eat durian?"

Comment: We ask that users provide an explanation with their answers. Please [edit] your answer to explain why your answer is right.